# why does this ruby code not return anything?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take a number and return a string with dashes around any odd numbers. Also, the string should not begin or end with a dash.

I've written the following but it does not return anything:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  string = num.to_s
  i = 0

  while i<string.length
    if (string[i].to_i % 2) != 0
      string[i] = '-' + string[i] + '-'
    end
    i += 1
  end

  if string[0] == '-'
    string.pop(1)
  end

  if (string.length - 1) == '-'
    string.pop(1)
  end

  string
end
```

It appears to be looping infinitely if I understand correctly; the console shows no output and doesn't allow me to do anything else unless I refresh. I've reviewed the code by each character, but I can't figure where it goes wrong.

Comment: As the author has mentioned in his/her question, the method has been called in the console. @hac13 see my answer below. The problem seems to be in `while` loop.

Comment: @Uzbekjon Where does the OP say the method has been called in the console?

Comment: I'm not too sure what 'calling' a method means, but if it means running it - I have entered 'dasherize_number(4567)' and the console doesn't allow me to do much else

Comment: @hac13 You have to write that in the question.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Will remember to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of logical issues in your code.
here's something that might just work for you

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  string = num.to_s
  str_len = string.length

  i = 0

  while i < str_len
    next if string[i] == '-'
    if (string[i].to_i % 2) != 0
      string[i] = '-' + string[i] + '-'
      str_len = string.length
      i += 3
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end

  if string[0] == '-'
    string = string[1..-1]
  end

  if (string[string.length - 1]) == '-'
    string = string[0..-2]
  end

  string.gsub('--', '-')
end
```

**Explaination**

1. Firstly, you had this condition in your while loop `i < string.length`
   Which wouldn't work, because the length of the string keeps changing. So i've used a variable to store the value and update the variable if the string is updated.
2. If the string is updated, we can be sure that we can skip the next two indexes.
   eg: number inputed -> 122
   then after first iteration the string would be `-1-22`
   so we don't want to run the same condition for the next index because, that would be `1` again, hence the infinite loop. (Hope you get the idea)
3. `pop` wouldn't work on string, just because we can access characters using indexes like for arrays, we can't use `pop` for strings.
4. To make sure there are no consecutive dashes, i've used `gsub` to replace them with single dash.

Comment: All of it makes sense. I see it now. The only trouble is I get one extra dash when there are two odd numbers next to each other. My fault for not making it clear there. When I call the function for (333) I get '3--3--3' instead of '3-3-3'; need only one dash in between.

Comment: @hac13 Please see the last edit. This should remove consecutive dashes

Comment: Magic! That was the missing piece, and another new thing learned

Comment: Tried but unfortunately it won't count until I have 15 points

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this part of the code:

```
while i<string.length
    if (string[i].to_i % 2) != 0
        string[i] = '-' + string[i] + '-'
    end
    i += 1
end
```

If your `string` contains odd number it increases its length by 2 more chars (2x`-`), but incrementing it by 1 (`i+=1`).

Assign initial string length to a var and check its length in the `while` loop.

```
string_length = string.length

while i < string_length
    if ((string[i].to_i % 2) != 0)
        string[i] = '-' + string[i] + '-'
    end
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: Did you test this code?  I think there's a surprise here for you...  :)

Comment: No, I did not. I just pointed out the logical problem I could spotted. The rest, I think, is the job of the question author. But, now you got me interested! :) Share what else could you spot?

Comment: I see... the `()` around `if`! Yeap! :)

Comment: I don't see that. are you referring to line 5?

Comment: @Uzbekjon good point there. that's exactly what was going wrong. I think since string.length is now greater than string_length I wouldn't loop through the whole string. for example if the string is '12', then the loop would go through '1-' and not go through the '2'. I've figured the best way is to store the characters in another variable.